# Trust Boundary Violation php

Tags: php

I did a scan with CheckMarx, and they made several errors discovering Trust Boundary violations, I tried several techniques but I can't solve the problem:( can you help me fix it?

The error is displayed for all my $_SESSION

My processing page:

```
public static function LoginVerification($email, $password){
// Connexion bdd
include("./function/conn.php"); // Connexion à la base de donnée
// Sécurisation données envoyer BDD
$email = Securite::bdd($email);
$password = Securite::bdd($password);

//  Récupération de l'utilisateur et de sont mot de passe
$resultat = pg_prepare($conn_qualys,"log",'SELECT
  utilisateurs.id, --0
  utilisateurs.prenom,  --1
  utilisateurs.nom, --2
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_id, --3
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_fret, --4
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_dosn_infra,   --5
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_voyage, --6
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_region, --7
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_reseau, --8
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_autres, --9
  utilisateurs.email, --10
  utilisateurs.password, --11
  utilisateurs.niveau, --12
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_applications, --13
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_all, --14
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_gares, --15
  app_utilisateurs_droit.droit_dsifis --16
  FROM utilisateurs INNER JOIN app_utilisateurs_droit ON app_utilisateurs_droit.id = utilisateurs.id WHERE utilisateurs.email = $1');
  $resultat = pg_execute($conn_qualys,"log",array( $email ));
  if (!$resultat || !pg_fetch_row($resultat)) {
    echo '<div class="erreur_mdp"><p class="text">L"email ou le mot de passe est incorrect.</p></div>';
  } else {
    if (pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 11) == null) {
      echo 'Erreur dans le mot de passe';
    } else {
      $bdd_password = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 11); // Variable pour récuperer les élèment renseigner en base de donnée
      // Comparaison du pass envoyé via le formulaire avec la base
      if (password_verify($password, $bdd_password)) {  // Connexion a l'application si bon mot de passe et adresse e-mail.
        if ($_SESSION['email'] == null) {
          echo 'erreur dans email';
        } else {
          $_SESSION['email'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 10);
        }
        $_SESSION['password'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 11);
        $_SESSION['name'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 2);
        $_SESSION['prenom'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 1);
        $_SESSION['niveau'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 12);
        $_SESSION['droit_id'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 3);
        $_SESSION['droit_fret'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 4);
        $_SESSION['droit_dosn_infra'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 5);
        $_SESSION['droit_voyage'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 6);
        $_SESSION['droit_region'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 7);
        $_SESSION['droit_reseau'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 8);
        $_SESSION['droit_autres'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 9);
        $_SESSION['droit_applications'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 13);
        $_SESSION['droit_all'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 14);
        $_SESSION['droit_gares'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 15);
        $_SESSION['droit_dsifs'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 16);
        $_SESSION['id_utilisateurs'] = pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 0);
        $token = Securite::bytes();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        header("location: ./index.php");
      } else
       {
        echo '<div class="erreur_mdp"><p class="text">L"email ou le mot de passe est incorrect.</p></div>';
       }
    }
  }
}
```

My page that calls the functions :

```
<?php

function autoloadClass($class)
{
  require "classes/" . $class . ".php";
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloadClass');

$verifConnexion = Connexion::VerifConnexion();

// Chargement du css pour la page de connexion
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style_connexion.css">
    <title>Connexion</title>
  </head>
  <body>';

// Function pour afficher le formulaire de connexion
$PageConnexion = Connexion::PageConnexion();

// Vérification si les champs sont bien indiquer
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
$ConnexionVerif = Connexion::LoginVerification(Securite::bdd($_POST['email']), Securite::bdd($_POST['password']));
} else {
  echo '<div class="LoginVerification"><center>Merci de saisir vos identifiants // Version Alpha 2.0</center></div>';
}

echo '</body>
</html>';
```

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: which type of error you get?

Comment: you'll have to be more specific about what problems are identified. Do they point to specific lines of code? Also don't assume that we have any idea what "checkmarx" is, what it does, or what you were using it for. You can assume we have general knowledge of PHP, but not of particular commercial products. Please give us more details. P.S. as a general point about the reported error message, you might find [this](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/501.html) to be useful information

Comment: P.S. As a general point, it seems crazy to add all these pieces of information to the session in separate keys. You do you know you can add objects and arrays to the session directly, right? So you could store the whole user object inside one session key. Although `$_SESSION['password']` ...no, you should never do that. There should never be any need for that. Once the user is logged in, you don't need to know their password. It's just asking to be hacked.

Comment: Hello, I plan to delete the "$_SESSION['password'], the error checkmarx tells me security level is as follows:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzx5b.png

Answer (score 0):

Trust Boundary Violation in Checkmarx simply indicates that your code is placing untrusted data (in this case data from pg_fetch_result call) into your server side Session which is a trusted store.

It is advisable to validate and sanitize input from pg_fetch_result before assigning it to the $_SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = filter_var(pg_fetch_result($resultat, 0, 10),FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```